# Java Lucene Filters seem not to alter the query search space as expected (by me)

Tags: java, lucene, tf-idf, lucene-filters

**THIS QUESTION HAS BEEN EDITED AFTER NEW FINDINGS**

I am using `DefaultSimilarity` (TFIDF) to search a sample index with 4 documents. When using a filtered query I noticed that while it reduces the number of results correctly it does not alter the document scores. This made me very suspicious...

So I extended `DefaultSimilarity` to print out the `tf*id`f values of: `term_frequency`, `total_number_of_documents`, and `document_frequency` and I indeed confirmed that these values do not change at all. I was expecting `numDocs` and `docFreq` to reflect the smaller search space introduced by the filter. (Read [here](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/2009/02/filtering-a-lucene-search.html) if you have time)

This is my document collection (text is a TextField):

```
id=0 type=type.colors title=This is a black dog
id=1 type=type.pets title=This is a black cat
id=2 type=type.colors title=The cat is white
id=3 type=type.pets title=The cat is black
```

When I search for "black":

```
Query query = parser.parse("black");
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, 5);
```

I get `numDocs=4` and `docFreq=3` as expected.

I then tried to reduce the search space in the following ways:

1)

```
PrefixFilter prefixFilter = new PrefixFilter(new Term("type", "type.colors"));
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, prefixFilter, 5);
```

2)

```
PrefixQuery categoryQuery = new PrefixQuery(new Term("type", "type.colors"));
QueryWrapperFilter categoryFilter = new QueryWrapperFilter(categoryQuery);
TopDocs results = searcher.search(query, categoryFilter, 5);
```

3)

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
booleanQuery.add(new PrefixQuery(new Term("type", "type.colors")), Occur.MUST);
booleanQuery.add(blackQuery, Occur.MUST);
```

And I always end up with the same values of numDocs and docFreq. (`instead of numDocs=2 and docFreq=1` since the search space should have been reduced to 2 documents and only 1 of them contains "black");

It seems that either those values are pre-calculated at index creation or that the filter is applied after the query returns. I'm not happy with either of the alternatives...

How can I have Lucene calculate those values after the filter has been applied?

Full gist [here](https://gist.github.com/gevorghari/7438048)

Answer (score 1):

Scores aren't really comparable between different queries.  The fact that you get the same score between two different queries isn't really a meaningful result.  You are getting the correct results in the correct order.  The fact that they happen to be equal just gets into implementation details.  Scores are only comparable between documents returned as part of the same query.

You can call [IndexSearcer.explain](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#explain%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int%29), to get a better unnderstanding of why things get the scores they get.

Comment: Thanks but I am interested in the internal details in this case. :)  Scores should not be compared between queries because they can change over several different factors. In this case I have 3 different queries that produce the same score and that is weird. I know how the DefaultSimilarity works and the filtered result scores do not match the implementation behind it. I believe that the filter is applied after the query (that would justify the scores) and I'd like the opposite behavior instead. Also, is there an IndexSearcher.explain equivalent to explain filters or filtered queries?

Comment: `IDF(t) = 1 + log(numDocs/(docFreq + 1))` is the IDF calculation, so we have `1+log(2/2) = 1+log(4/4) = 1`.  According to the algorithm given in the [TFIDFSimilarity documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html), the IDF scoring element should indeed be equal, and I don't see anything that would cause differences in tf, querynorm, coord, boost, or norm.  The two filtered queries should be effectively identical to each other.

Comment: Thanks for following up! I agree for the term "black"! The following are my calculations for regularQuery vs filteredQuery: IDF(black) = 1+log(4/3+1) = 1+log(2/1+1) = 1. Note that both numDocs and docFreq vary in a way that leads to the same idf for "black". What about "dog"? Shouldn't 1+log(4/1+1) != 1+log(2/1+1)? Dog is rarer when considering a search space of 4 documents and should have a higher idf for the regular query. Don't know much about the other scoring elements, do you think that they might somehow make the two scores exactly the same? Will run more tests tomorrow.

Comment: Yes, good point, wasn't thinking about that term, to be honest, since it seemed less interesting.  My mistake.  Does give the impression that the filter's restriction doesn't impact IDF scoring.  It's possible queryNorm could be causing this, as it's intended to make scores more comparable, and I haven't quite wrapped my head around it yet.  I doubt it, though.  May have to come back to this later when I've had a chance to do some tinkering with it.

Comment: I discovered a few things and updated my question accordingly. A gist of my experimentation is here: https://gist.github.com/gevorghari/7438048